# Update Android SDK Platform Tools via Command line

Tags: updates, command-line, android-sdk

I want to write a script to update the Android SDK platform tools and I need the command if available to run in order to achieve this. What I have found is that I can use the Android command under the `/tools` directory to update the software (images, sources, etc.), but nothing to update the tools themselves.

The guide on [Factory Images for Nexus Devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) says that I must be sure I have the latest tools

> Be sure that you have the latest version of the Android SDK Platform-tools from the SDK Manager.

So, is it possible? If it is, how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

Use of `android` tool is deprecated; instead use `sdkmanager`:

```
 androidsdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager.html

Answer (score 5):

After further research, I came across this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712812/how-to-update-android-platform-tools-in-a-headless-linux) from Stack Overflow 
that explains it and states that the Android command that can be used to update the `platform-tools` in the SDK directory.

You follow these instructions as shown on the above link

> ```
> $ android list sdk
> $ android update sdk --no-ui --filter 1,platform-tools
> ```
>
> The first command lists the available packages that are still to be
>   installed (indexed by number), as for example:
>
> ```
> Packages available for installation or update: 9
>    1- Android SDK Tools, revision 19
>    2- Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 11
>    ...
> ```
>
> According to that list, you can issue the second command to install
>   the packages that you want to install.
>
> The `--filter` option limits the update to the packages that you want to
>   install. You specify those packages in a comma-separated format. Also,
>   you can filter them by the index number provided in the listing
>   resulting from the first command.

Comment: What does **--filter 1** do here?